# Mapping the first element in a 3 element's cell matrix

Tags: numpy, image-processing

TL;DR:
Given a np.array of a shape (M,N,3), what is the most efficient way to change the first element in each of [M,N] values?

Hello,

As part of an image processing course I’m taking, I need to manually quantizing an image.
If my input is in an `RGB` format, I first need to transform it into a `YIQ` format and then perform quantization over the `Y` values. In that process I build a table that maps each value of `Y` into a new value, `Y'`. Next, I need to construct an image of the same shape with `Y'` values instead of `Y`, and the same values for `I` and `Q`. Lastly, I transform the new image, `Y'IQ` back into `RGB` format.

I'm having a trouble in the mapping process. I already have the table that relates `Y` to `Y'`, but I had not succeed in the transformation process.

My image is in a float format with a shape of `(12,13,3)` (for example). I need to transform only the first element on each cell (which consists 3 elements).

I used the following loop

```
for n in range(0, imgYIQ.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, imgYIQ.shape[1]):
        imgYIQ2[n, j][0] = (1 / 255) * Ttable['h(v)'][Ttable['v'] == imgYIQ2[n, j, 0]]
```

Where `Ttable` is the table which maps any value of `Y` into `Y'`. I used the loop because I wanted to condition on the image old value (`[Ttable['v'] == imgYIQ2[n, j, 0]]`).

Is there a way to make this process vectorized?

Comment: If your I and Q channels remain unchanged and you are only transforming Y, have you considered splitting the channels or creating a view onto just the Y channel?

Comment: Thank you very much it worked and saved me a lot of computing time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Mark Serchell approach. I first turned my (h,w,d) array into (h*w,d) one. In my case, the result was (h*w,3).
Then, turned the (h8*w,3) array into (h*w,3) pd.DataFrame.
Having the mapping table already, I had only to use `pd.merge(., sort = False)`, validate that the order of the original array of (h*w,3) stayed the same (I validate it using the fact that `YIQ`.loc[:,1] == `Y'IQ`.loc[:,1] and `YIQ`.loc[:,2] == `Y'IQ`.loc[:,2]).

After I had `Y'IQ` in a (h*w,3) df, I turned it into an np.array (using `pd.DataFrame.to_numpy`) and then I reshaped the resulted array into the old shape (h,w,3).